# VSCode set breakpoints in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to debug typescript using vscode, I tried to set breakpoints in my typescript source file. Here is my `launch.json`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${file}",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
            ],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "sourceMaps": true,
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I use `gulp` to watch typescript and compile them to `.js`. Here is `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "files": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "removeComments": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "types": [
            "node",
            "lodash"
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

But when I set breakpoints in typescript file, there comes the error: `cannt launch the program src/xxx.ts because corresponding JavaScript cannot be found.` I have checked that `gulp` has compiled `.ts` into `dist/`

Comment: Why would you want to do that? You can easily debug your application in chrome console. If you want to put breakpoint in typescript not transpiled JavaScript than I would suggest you to use source maps for that purpose.

Comment: Yes, I have used source maps.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
"outFiles": [
    "${workspaceRoot}/dist/**/*.js"
],
```

You should use

`"outDir": "${workspaceRoot}/dist"`

Comment: The newest vscode suggest me not use `outDir` but `outFiles`

Comment: I know, but I never get outFiles work for debugging typescript.

Comment: [working example](https://github.com/Asing1001/movieRater.React) for typescript breakpoint

Comment: this doesn't work for me, and where are your source maps files? Mine is in `dist/maps/`

Comment: mine is along with js files